# Perl - Why does shift lose its value after being used?

Tags: regex, perl, variables, shift

This code works - It takes an array of full txt file paths and strips them so that when `$exam_nums[$x]` is called, it returns the file name

```
for (0..$#exam_nums)
{
 $exam_nums[$_] =~ s/\.txt$//; #remove extension
 $exam_nums[$_] =~ s/$dir//g; #remove path
}
```

When I try to do this for a single variable, it doesn't work.  I'm calling a subroutine and sending it a present, but the variable is empty at the end.  (It is getting into the if statement block, because the other lines in there run fine.)  Here's the code:

Call to the sub:

```
notify($_);
```

The `$_` is from a `foreach(@files)` loop that works

The sub:

```
sub notify
{
 if(shift)
 { 
  $ex_num = shift;
  $ex_num =~ s/\.txt$//; #remove extension
  $ex_num =~ s/$dir//g; #remove path
        print $ex_num;
        print "\nanything";
 }
}
```

I tried taking out the `$` in the "remove extension" portion of the regex, but that didn't help.

Comment: When you run into these problems, print the value of the variable before you use it to verify that it has the value you think it does.

Comment: @brian - i like to live on the edge... but seriously... the real problem was that I didn't know that asking if shift existed would destroy it... before passing it to the function, it would print.  after the function, it wouldn't

Comment: When you don't know what a Perl built-in will do, read its documentation. Still, printing the values before and after will help you. There's a lot you can do to help yourself, and you should try to do that before asking a question.

Comment: i understand... sometimes I don't even know where to start, hence the phrasing of the question.... I thought this problem was in the regex and not the usage of shift(s)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're shifting TWICE. The first shift in the if statement removes the value, the second shift gets nothing.  `shift` has a side-effect of actually modifying `@_`. in addition to returning the first element, it removes the first element permanently from `@_`.

EDIT: from `man perlfunc`

```
   shift ARRAY
   shift   Shifts the first value of the array off and returns it,
           shortening the array by 1 and moving everything down.  If there
           are no elements in the array, returns the undefined value.  If
           ARRAY is omitted, shifts the @_ array within the lexical scope
           of subroutines and formats, ...
```

Comment: so when I test for a shift I'm actually destroying that pointer?

Comment: You're removing an item for the array, testing whether it's true, and then throwing it away. That item isn't there anymore, and the next shift gets the *next* item, if there is one.

Comment: the way i originally thought things were happening was: i send a function a variable [shifted from @files array], then the function tests if it was handed a variable at all [if(shift)], and if it was, deal with it.... I don't fully understand shift and/or $_ i suppose.

Comment: I've added a quote from the perlfunc manpage that explains it pretty clearly.  `shift` by itself acts on @_

Comment: .... see what kind of sh*t happens when you try teaching yourself without fully learning the basics?

Answer (score 6):

You are attempting to extract your `ex_num` argument from `@_` (the argument list) twice: `shift` (which alters `@_`) is not the same as `$_[0]` (which just looks at the first element of `@_` but does not alter it). See [perldoc -f shift](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html).

Also, your function is closing over `$dir`, which may or may not be your intent. (See [perldoc perlfaq7](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq7.html#What%27s-a-closure%3F) for more information about closures.)  I've taken that out and added it as an additional function parameter:

```
sub notify
{
    my ($ex_num, $dir) = @_;
    return unless $ex_num;

    $ex_num =~ s/\.txt$//; # remove extension
    $ex_num =~ s/$dir//g;  # remove path
    print $ex_num . "\n";
}
```

Comment: the subroutine can be called with or without the argument, thats why I tested for it right off the bat... I see where you are going with the return unless, but I actually need it to hang around even if nothing is given to it

Comment: The code I wrote does the same (logical) thing as what your original does: if there is no ex_num parameter passed to the function, it does nothing. You should of course not short-circuit if there is other stuff to do in the function (that you omitted from your example due to lack of relevance). :)

Answer (score 5):

I'd use [File::Basename](http://search.cpan.org/~dapm/perl-5.10.1/lib/File/Basename.pm) instead of rolling my own. It allows you to parse file paths into their directory, filename and suffix.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Jim Garrison's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765279/what-am-i-missing-here-perl-regex/1765382#1765382) info, I pulled a switch to fix the problem:

```
sub notify
{
    $ex_num = shift;
    if($ex_num)
    {   
        $ex_num =~ s/\.txt$//; #remove extension
        $ex_num =~ s/$dir//g; #remove path
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uses a core module, local variables and Perl 5.10.

```
use 5.010;
use File::Basename;

sub notify {
    my $ex_num = shift;
    my $name = basename($ex_num, '.txt');
    say $name;
}
```